# session problem between Reactjs and Laravel, (Error 401 -Unauthenticated)

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, session

I want to check whether the user is logged in or not, hence I send a get request (with axios) to the server (endpoint `../islogin`) - Unfortunately we use session in this project and I'm thinking whenever the get request goes to the server, the session is restarted and a new session is created on the server, so I faced 401 error.

Note, we don't have this problem on the server, only in the development.

How can I do this correctly?

[image: the response error]

[image]

Comment: Your routes are protected. Server is expecting a token and you are not providing it by not sending via header

Comment: if you are sending a request cross origin and want to use the session you need to specify the option `withCredentials: true` in axios. Otherwise it will not send the session cookie and the server will create a new session

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `session_start();` in `bootstrap/app.php` and then try hope this will resolve your issue.